# CSS: Any tests on when two classes give an element different values?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I mean:

```
<h1 class="red blue">Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

And in CSS:

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

It is pretty easy to test it yourself in a browser, but I was wondering if there are any existing tests done on a wide range of browsers and mobile devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't vary from browser to browser but instead follows the guidelines of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In your particular case the color will always be blue because the blue selector has the same level of specificity as the red selector but was defined later and whatever is defined later trumps that which is defined earlier for equal specificity.